# :class binding not working in IE or Iphone 8 - VUE JS

Tags: css, vue.js, internet-explorer, cross-browser

Having some issues with a navigation drop down in my application. It works fine across chrome and edge, when the class is toggled, the classes switch. We're needing to work on IE as well as older phone models like the Iphone 8.

I've combed through the CSS and this doesn't seem to be the issue. I'm wondering if the way I have my class binding set up is calling an issue on the older device / browsers.

```
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      navigation: false
    }
  },
  computed: {
    setNavigation() {
      return this.navigation ? 'navigation-outer' : 'navigation-outer-hidden';
    }
  },
  methods: {
    toggleNavigation() {
      this.navigation ? this.navigation = false : this.navigation = true;
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

```
<div :class="setNavigation"> 

Navigation content.

</div>
```

Comment: `It works fine ...` What do you mean by that ? What's the normal behaviour and the behaviour that you get on IE ?

Comment: Sorry, I've edited the post. The classes toggle successfully on Chrome.

Comment: by IE you mean IE11? By the way, a shorter version to toggle your navigation would be `this.navigation = !this.navigation` . You can drop the whole ternary in your toggleNavigation() method

Comment: For testing purposes, Try to return navigation: true and check results. If possible then try to provide a sample using JSFiddle. so that we can see it's effect on the IE browser. You can try to refer to these examples. https://jsfiddle.net/mjdwebdesign/KsAZ8/ and https://jsfiddle.net/solodev/urLn1L4u/